# Is there an easy way to revert the changes that SQL Azure Data Sync Tool does to a local database?

Tags: sql, azure, synchronization, revert

I tried using the [SQL Azure Data Sync Tool](http://www.stephenforte.net/PermaLink,guid,0098a65c-924a-45e8-bd7d-49cade40c094.aspx) and successfully transfered a local database from my dev machine to a SQL Azure account. However, later on I noticed that the tool has silently made a bunch of changes to my local database - definitely not a nice thing to do without any notification or confirmation dialog.

Does anybody know if there is an easy way to revert the changes(added stored procedures and tracking tables) that the sync tool has made? I know manually deleting stuff is always an option, but it's rather error prone I would consider it my last resort.

Comment: You could reload from the backup you shot just before you ran the tool against your database. (Yeah, I always forget to do that, too.)

Comment: I made a backup and appreciate your constructive irony, Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sync tool is used to keep a SQL Azure database in sync with your local SQL database. The tracking tables are necessary to keep the tables in sync as the data changes. It works in a similar fashion to SQL Server [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151329.aspx). I am not aware of an automatic way to do that right now. Merge Replication has tools and SPROCS floating around to do this but it took a while for them to come out.

If you just want to copy a database to SQL Azure you should script it, which is easy to do with SSMS, or use some other method. The sync tool is not a good way to just copy a database.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Matt. I ended up recovering from a backup, but I think the data sync tool should at least state explicitly that it will mess with the structure of your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Q: How do I manually deprovision a database?

A. A standalone executable is installed with the LocalAgentSetup.msi that you can use to de-provision the SQL Data Sync objects that are created when you add a database or table to your synchronization service.

MSDN Article [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667301.aspx#bkmk_manuallydeprovision).

Comment: Is that really an answer to the question asked?